# Which one is greater in the complex series $\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{-4},...\sqrt{-n}$??

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

While standing in a queue tokens were given to every one with increasing order of numbers to decide that who will enter $1^{st}$ and who will go $2^{nd}$ and so on, at that moment a very interested question arrived in my mind that if the numbers written on the tokens were imaginary numbers then who will go $1^{st}$ and who will go $2^{nd}$ who will go third and so no.

So my question is this that what is the increasing order of $$\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{-4},...\sqrt{-n}$$ $$OR$$ $$i,i\sqrt2,i\sqrt3,i\sqrt4,i\sqrt5,i\sqrt6...$$

where $n\in \mathbb N$

Please help me!!!

Comment: Complex numbers (and imaginary numbers) are not ordered. Of course you can come up with your own rule for ordering (e.g based on magnitude).

Comment: This concept of one complex number being greater than second complex number does not exist, you can only compare their modulus (which is a real number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no increasing order of complex numbers. But their modulus will have increasing order. Because the modulus make the complex number in real number and real numbers have increasing order

Answer (score 1):

Thing about orderings is that they have to follow certain minimal axioms that don't necessarily correspond to what you think of. I can come up with some crazy ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ which has nothing to do with what we usually think of, and it can still work.

Now, the canonical ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is compatible with its arithmetic operations (we call this an ordered field). When you hash out the details, you have that any number squared must be nonnegative in that kind of ordering, which breaks in $\mathbb{C}$, so for that reason we don't usually attribute any ordering to it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are concerned about the magnitude, the current order is correct. This is because

$|{\sqrt{-n}}|=\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt\cdot$ is monotonically increasing wrt $n$.
Therefore

$$|\sqrt{-1}|<|\sqrt{-2}|<|\sqrt{-3}|<|\sqrt{-4}|<...<|\sqrt{-n}|$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{C}$ does not have a "standard" ordering like $\mathbb{R}$ does, which means it doesn't make sense to immediately discuss which number is "bigger than another". However, the modulus $|z|$ indicates the magnitude/length of $z$ which is how size of complex numbers is typically compared.